# Relation between users and country table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Im trying to get the user country but isnt working, my example code is:

User Model:

```
public function countryName()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Country');
    }


Tables:
User:
- id;
- name;
- country_id;

Countries:
-id ;
- name;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set relation as:

```
public function country()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Country');
}
```

To get the country do this:

```
$user->country->name;
```

Comment: not working, giving me a error of SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'countries.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `countries` where `countries`.`user_id` = 7 and `countries`.`user_id` is not null limit 1) (View: